# How to write a table literal in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

A table with one column and one row can be created with:

```
select 'create' as col from dual;
```

This can be used to build table joins:

```
with
  a as (select 'create' as ac from dual),
  b as (select 'delete' as bc from dual)
select * from a left outer join b on (ac = bc);
```

Now I would like to have two rows. I did it in this way:

```
select 'create' as col from dual
union
select 'delete' as col from dual;
```

But is there a more compact notation for this? I tried

```
select ('create', 'delete') as col from dual;
```

but it does not work.

Comment: do you need specific strings? or random(ish) ones?

Comment: @Randy: random. 'create' and 'delete' for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use collection type and TABLE operator, for example (works in Oracle 10g):

```
SQL> SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('abc', 'def', 'ghi'));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways to generate rows. You could use rownum against a table with a larger number of rows:

```
SELECT roWnum AS a
  FROM user_objects
  WHERE rownum <= 3
```

You could use a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT level AS a
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
```

EDIT: change int sequence to alpha sequence:

```
SELECT CHR( ASCII('a') + level - 1 )
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
```

Comment: Sorry I used integers in my example but I actually need strings.

Comment: Sorry again. The table data can not be calculated.