# Is there a non-ugly way to use a multi-column, multi-row table literal in an Oracle 11g query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, literals

I'm trying to use a "literal" multi-column table for a join query with Oracle 11g.

Here's the best I've come up with, based on [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/985742/20789) (
[this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/11470674/20789) suggests a much nicer syntax, but it only works for a *single-column* table as far as I can tell):

```sql
SELECT * from
(
 -- The ugly... it burns...
 select 'APPLE' as n, 'FRUIT' as m from dual
 union all select 'CARROT' as n, 'VEGGIE' as m from dual
 union all select 'PEACH' as n, 'FRUIT' as m from dual
 union all select 'CUCUMBER' as n, 'VEGGIE' as m from dual
 union all select 'ORANGE' as n, 'FRUIT' as m from dual
)
```

Is there a less ugly way to create a multi-row, multi-column literal table in Oracle? Unfortunately, I **cannot** create temporary tables.

`<rant>`As I've come to expect, PostgreSQL has a [nice, sane syntax for literal tables](//www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-values.html), but Oracle is a mess.`</rant>`

**EDIT:** I had tried the [row-value constructor syntax](//docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions015.htm#SQLRF52079) as [suggested by @Mark Chesney](//stackoverflow.com/a/29903447/20789) but that doesn't work either: `select n,m from dual where (n,m) in (...)` gives me an Invalid Identifier error.

Comment: For multicolumn tables with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469634/how-to-write-a-table-literal-in-oracle/11470674#11470674 solution you can join two (or more) `select * from table()` queries

Comment: @agent5566, what would I use as the join condition, given that each of the tables to be joined contains only one column?

Comment: `ROWNUM` of each subquery

Answer (score 8):

For two columns you can use ODCIObjectList:

```
select objectschema m, objectname n
  from table(sys.ODCIObjectList(
    sys.odciobject('APPLE', 'FRUIT'), 
    sys.odciobject('CARROT', 'VEGGIE'),
    sys.odciobject('PEACH', 'FRUIT'),
    sys.odciobject('CUCUMBER', 'VEGGIE'),
    sys.odciobject('ORANGE', 'FRUIT')));

M          N         
---------- ----------
APPLE      FRUIT     
CARROT     VEGGIE    
PEACH      FRUIT     
CUCUMBER   VEGGIE    
ORANGE     FRUIT
```

For more columns you can define your own types:

```
create type t as object (a varchar2(10), b varchar2(10), c number);
create type tt as table of t;

select * from table( tt (
    t('APPLE', 'FRUIT', 1),
    t('APPLE', 'FRUIT', 1122), 
    t('CARROT', 'VEGGIE', 3),
    t('PEACH', 'FRUIT', 104),
    t('CUCUMBER', 'VEGGIE', 5),
    t('ORANGE', 'FRUIT', 6) ) )

A          B                   C
---------- ---------- ----------
APPLE      FRUIT               1 
APPLE      FRUIT            1122 
CARROT     VEGGIE              3 
PEACH      FRUIT             104 
CUCUMBER   VEGGIE              5 
ORANGE     FRUIT               6
```

Comment: Thanks. This is still ugly (obviously not your fault!), but it's the least ugly solution I've seen so far. I can't `CREATE TYPE` either on this server but this'll work for the 2-column lookup.

Comment: If you can't define types then there are some [predefined](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcicnstnts.htm#i76582) which may suit you, not many of them.

Answer (score 6):

For many columns you can join like this

```
SELECT a.v field1, b.v field2
  FROM (SELECT column_value v, rownum r
          FROM TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('abc', 'def', 'ghi'))) a
  JOIN (SELECT column_value v, rownum r
          FROM TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('abc', 'def', 'ghi'))) b ON a.r = b.r
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 23, you can use the `VALUES` syntax:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ( VALUES ('APPLE', 'FRUIT'),
                ('CARROT', 'VEGGIE'),
                ('PEACH', 'FRUIT'),
                ('CUCUMBER', 'VEGGIE'),
                ('ORANGE', 'FRUIT')
       ) t (m, n);
```

In earlier versions, you can use `SELECT ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL ...` and wrap it in a sub-query factoring clause (a CTE in other SQL dialects) and name the columns in the signature to simplify the query:

```sql
WITH t (m, n) AS (
  select 'APPLE',    'FRUIT'  from dual union all
  select 'CARROT',   'VEGGIE' from dual union all
  select 'PEACH',    'FRUIT'  from dual union all
  select 'CUCUMBER', 'VEGGIE' from dual union all
  select 'ORANGE',   'FRUIT'  from dual
)
SELECT * from t
```

Which both output:

| M | N |
| --- | --- |
| APPLE | FRUIT |
| CARROT | VEGGIE |
| PEACH | FRUIT |
| CUCUMBER | VEGGIE |
| ORANGE | FRUIT |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DAGwvW1m)